# Copy PDF from source folder to destination folder

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, directory

I want copy pdf from source folder and have to paste in destpath based on Excel, help me where I am gone wrong

```
Sub CheckandSend()   
    Dim irow As Integer   
    Dim DestPath As String   
    Dim SourcePath As String   
    Dim pfile As String  

    Dim FSO As Object   
    Dim Fldr As Object, f As Object   

    SourcePath = "I:\Mechanical\ExternalProjects\Cummins Emission Systems\35101124 PT Cup Test Rig\16 PDF to Vendor" 
  
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
    Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder(SourcePath).Files 

    DestPath = "P:\CENTRAL PLANNING\PROJECTS 2020-2021\VAM-TARSON\Newfolder1"    

    irow = 7    
    Do While Cells(irow, 2) <> Empty    
        pfile = Dir(SourcePath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 2) & "*")        
        If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "PDF" Then       
            FileCopy SourcePath, DestPath           
            irow = irow + 1           
        End If         
    Loop      
end sub
```

Comment: The `SourcePath` must end on a backslash.

Comment: that too tried , no improvement

Comment: @ArunKumarG. there is no error description in your question. What went wrong? What errors did you get and where? Make sure the destination folder exists before you copy to it.

Comment: Note that in `FileCopy SourcePath, DestPath` there is only the path `SourcePath` but no file mentioned so it cannot know which file to copy. You need a file name appended to your `SourcePath`.

Comment: FileCopy SourcePath, DestPath , how can i add file name (pfile) to the Sourcepath , cause my file name (pfile) varies each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are mixing 2 different methods: The `FileSystemObject` and `Dir()`. Only use one of them.
2. `FileCopy SourcePath, DestPath` only copies the path but there is no filename.
3. Directly include the file extension in your `Dir()` so you don't need to check for pdf files:

   ```
   FileName = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & ws.Cells(iRow, 2) & "*.pdf")
   ```
4. There may exist more than one file with the key word from your cell. Your code copies randomly one of them. Make sure to loop so you get all of them

   ```
   Do While FileName <> vbNullString 'if more files with the key word from ws.Cells(iRow, 2) exist copy all of them
       VBA.FileCopy SourcePath & pfile, DestPath 'copy needs to be path AND filename
       FileName = Dir()
   Loop
   ```

It could look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckandSend()
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'make sure to define a sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim SourcePath As String
    SourcePath = "C:\Temp\" 'make sure paths end with \

    Dim DestPath As String
    DestPath = "P:\CENTRAL PLANNING\PROJECTS 2020-2021\VAM-TARSON\Newfolder1\" 'make sure paths end with \
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    iRow = 7
    
    Do While ws.Cells(iRow, 2) <> vbNullString
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = Dir(SourcePath & "*" & ws.Cells(iRow, 2) & "*.pdf") 'this will only go through pdf files
        
        Do While FileName <> vbNullString 'if more files with the key word from ws.Cells(iRow, 2) exist copy all of them
            VBA.FileCopy SourcePath & pfile, DestPath 'copy needs to be path AND filename
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
        
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works.

```
Sub CheckandSend()
    ' 191

    Const Ext           As String = ".pdf"
    Dim SourcePath      As String
    Dim DestPath        As String
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim Fldr            As Object
    Dim pFile As String
    Dim f As Object
    Dim iRow            As Long             ' row numbers should be declared as Long
    
    ' both paths must end on backslash ("\")
    SourcePath = "I:\Mechanical\ExternalProjects\Cummins Emission Systems\35101124 PT Cup Test Rig\16 PDF to Vendor\"
    DestPath = "P:\CENTRAL PLANNING\PROJECTS 2020-2021\VAM-TARSON\Newfolder1\"
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Fldr = FSO.GetFolder(SourcePath).Files
    
    ' loop until last used cell in column B
    For iRow = 7 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        pFile = Trim(Cells(iRow, 2).Value)
        If Len(pFile) = 0 Then Exit For     ' exit at first blank row
        
        If LCase(Right(pFile, 4)) <> Ext Then pFile = pFile & Ext
        If Len(Dir(SourcePath & pFile)) Then
            FileCopy SourcePath & pFile, DestPath & pFile
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

There are a few inconsistencies in your procedure which I have eliminated. For example, your code isn't clear whether the file name in the worksheet has a *pdf* extension or not, then looks for any file by that name but rejects all that aren't "pdf". The above code rephrases this to mean that you want a PDF file by the name in the worksheet and any file by the same name but another extension is to be ignored. It's the same, I think, but more efficient if you limit the search to PDF.

The other thing is the end of the loop. Is it when there are no more file names or when a cell is blank? The above code ends in either case. I presume that is OK because there are no blanks in your list of files. If so, it would be better, however, to just skip any accidental blanks and continue until the last line has been processed. If you agree, delete the `Exit For` and set an `End If` at the appropriate point (before the `Next iRow`) and indent all lines in between.